# K mean clustering

Tags: clustering, optimization, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour

I have coordinates data set (X.Y) with an additional attribute "Z". I want to cluster the data into 5 clusters based on X and Y but I want to add some constrains on how much the sum of "Z" can be at each cluster. How can I do that?

Comment: What are the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use clustering.

Formulate this as a **constraint optimization problem**, then solve that.